# JPA ManyToMany where annotation

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using JPA / EclipseLink 2.5.2 and want to add an additional where clause to my ManyToMany Mapping. The SQL Code would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Friends f
INNER JOIN User u ON f.friend_id = u.id 
WHERE f.verified=1;
```

So I managed to do the JoinMapping with:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name="User.login", query="SELECT a FROM User a WHERE a.username = :name and a.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name="User.findId", query="SELECT a FROM User a WHERE a.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name="User.findName", query="SELECT a FROM User a WHERE a.username = :name")

})
public class User implements Serializable {
...
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name="Friends"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="friend_id")
        }
    )
List<User> friends;
}
```

But I dont know how to add the `WHERE f.verified=1`

How can this be realized?

Thanks in advance,
Cassidy

Comment: You only defined the join between the tables. But how do you retrieve the entities? do you use NamedQuery or CriteriaQuery?

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582452/jpa-manytomany-how-can-jointable-have-a-property

Comment: The one User I retrieve via a NamedQuery and with the ManyToMany Mapping I want to retrieve the List<User> friends which contains all friends from the JoinTable "Friends" where "Friends.verified=1"

Comment: Not really a duplicate as this question is mainly about filtering the list. However you do also have the problem discussed in that question which is that the 'verified' flag is on the join table and therefore you do need to scrap the many-many-many and create an entity say 'Friendship' which has this additional property. You then create a one-to-many User > Friendship. Which is what this other question is discussing.

Comment: @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findXXX", query = "SELECT u FROM User u, IN(u.friends) f where f.verified=1"); Or you can use regular join: "SELECT u FROM User u Join u.friends f where f.verified=1"

Comment: But when i use @NamedQuery it is not possible to associate it with the member List<User> friends, is it?

Comment: this should work: "SELECT u FROM User u Join u.friends f where f.verified=1 AND u.username = :name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised in my comment you cannot use @ManyToMany as you require an additional column in the join table to indicate whether verified or not.

You then need to use a @OneToMany with an additional Entity, say Friendship. We can use the verified column as a discriminator and use a simple class hierarchy to distinguish between Unconfirmed and Confirmed friends.

This will then look something like the below (haven't tested it fully).

**Note, I tested this with Hibernate but there is an issue so will need to look at again. These posts suggests the issue may be Hibernate specific:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1631055/1356423.
- [Why @OneToMany does not work with inheritance in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057/why-onetomany-does-not-work-with-inheritance-in-hibernate)

**So may be worth trying with EclipseLink.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<ConfirmedFriendship> confirmedFriendships;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UnconfirmedFriendship> unconfirmedFriendships;

    public List<User> getConfirmedFriends() {
        return getFriends(confirmedFriendships);
    }

    public List<User> getUnconfirmedFriends() {
        return getFriends(unconfirmedFriendships);
    }

    private List<User> getFriends(Set<?  extends Friendship> friendships){
        List<User> friends = new ArrayList<User>();

        for(Friendship friendship : friendships) {
            friends.add(friendship.getFriend());
        }

        return friends;
    }
}
```

Base Entity for Friendship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "friendships")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "verified")
public abstract class Friendship {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id")
    private User friend;

    @Column(name = "verified")
    private boolean verified;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getFriend() {
        return friend;
    }

    public void setFriend(User friend) {
        this.friend = friend;
    }

    public boolean isVerified() {
        return verified;
    }

    public void setVerified(boolean verified) {
        this.verified = verified;
    }
}
```

Two subclassses which use the verified column as discriminator:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "1")
public class ConfirmedFriendship extends Friendship {

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "0")
public class UnconfirmedFriendship extends Friendship {

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: Out of interest, and given the issue I outlined with Hibernate,  does this work as is in EclipseLInk?

Comment: Yes, as far as I have tested it yet, it works fine with EclipseLink.

Comment: @Allstar I know this is old but can you please provide a working example? I cannot make it work (jpa2.1, eclipseLink 2.6.4). Everything is saved correctly in db, yet the `friendships` lists in user are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is JPA standard to include the "Where" option.
Personally I use NamedQuery to retrieve the entities. You can also use CriteriaQuery.

Well, In [eclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/toc.htm), you can use @AdditionalCriteria("this.verified=1")

Comment: When I use @AdditionalCriteria("this.verified=1") I need to create a new Entity doesn't I? Is it possible to connect a NamedQuery directly with a member variable? So i can still use the "List<User> friends" member in my User Class?

Comment: @AdditionalCriteria("this.verified=1") is entity level. I would suggest to use NamedQuery: "SELECT u FROM User u Join u.friends f where f.verified=1"